# Facebook app won't load newsfeed when using Wi-Fi on iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am having a problem which has driven me mad for months. When I am connected to my home Wi-Fi the Facebook app's newsfeed won't update. If I turn Wi-Fi off and use the mobile 3G it works fine so I guess its something to do with my Netgear router.

I have an iPhone 4 on iOS 6 and my router is a Netgear N150.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you updated to iOS 6.0.2? Or are you still on 6.0?

Comment: Im on 6.0.1 there doesnt seem to be any more available unless i can manually install 6.0.2 ?

Comment: Ahh...nevermind. Just realized 6.0.2 is only for iPad mini and iPhone 5. One sec...

Comment: Does Safari work in these conditions?

Comment: Safari works fine yes. Ive had to use facebook on the browser as the app wont work

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this is a problem on Facebook's end. The Android app also stopped working on WiFi for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few suggestions I could think of off the top of my head

- Restart your wifi radio (Settings > Wi-Fi > OFF. Leave off for 1 minute, then slide back to ON)
- Reboot your phone
- Reinstall Facebook app

Try those one at a time to see if any of them fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks but already tried them all :(

Comment: This may be a shot in the dark, but try reading here http://www.indiabroadband.net/bsnl-broadband/40234-problem-connecting-net-netgear-n150-dgn-1000-modem-router.html

Answer (score -1):

It might be your router. I had a n150 and it didn't work at all with my iPhone. I finally got another router which solved the problem for me.